# Unexpected assignment within ConditionalExpression

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a lib I got from GitHub and there is a strange condition I have never seen before, can someone help me understand what is this?
As I understand `_c = _b === null` means that _c get's a value of true or false... and later on _c !== undefined will always be true.. am I missing something?

```js
  const _b = { isWrappable: true, insertedTag: false };
  let _c;
  const status = (_c = _b === null || _b === undefined ? undefined : _b.isWrappable) !== null && _c !== undefined ? _c : false;
  console.log(status);
```

after this line `status` is `true`

Now, how can I change this line to avoid `Unexpected assignment within ConditionalExpression.` because everything I tried gives me `false`, for example:

```js
  const _b = { isWrappable: true, insertedTag: false };
  const _c = _b === null;
  const test = (_c || _b === undefined ? undefined : _b.isWrappable) !== null && _c !== undefined ? _c : false;
  console.log(test);
```

- _b is a variable, it can be null or undefined sometimes

Thanks

Comment: If _b can have different values perhaps declaring this something other than a constant would fix your issues.

Comment: It can't in *this* code; it's explicitly given a non-`null` value.

Comment: The `=` assignment sub-expression must be parenthesized. It's an issue of expression grammar operator precedence.

Comment: ^ this, I would take a step further and write a `_a` variable to split up the logic and make it `readable` as well

Comment: So how can I rewrite this, because if I set `const _b = { isWrappable: true, insertedTag: false };
  let _c;
  const test = ((_c = _b === null) || _b === undefined ? undefined : _b.isWrappable) !== null && _c !== undefined ? _c : false;
  console.log(test);`  test is false so it's not OK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it :) in my research I found Nullish coalescing operator  (??) and solved my problem
So the answer is

```js
const _b = {
  isWrappable: true,
  insertedTag: false
};
const status = _b?.isWrappable ?? false;
console.log(status);
```

The optional chaining operator and Nullish coalescing operator solved that mess.